# How can I disable the notification for received files on GNOME?

Tags: gnome, bluetooth, file-sharing

When I receive files over bluetooth, my system makes an annoying peep and gives an even more annoying popup for every single file. How can I disable this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to disable the notification from the GNOME-User-Share settings.

- Open Personal-File-Sharing from the system menu or Unity Dash.
- When it opens
  [image]
- Disable the "Notify about received files" option.

*I found this after I ran into the problem a little too often really needed a solution.*